# mongoose model.find query string

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with a query string of a mongoose model. The code below is working fine. But if I construct the same query as a String it is not working. 
The console output of "query" is

```
'diagnosis_text_de': /.*depression.*/i
```

I do not understand why this is not working and how to fix this.

working:

```
getByFullText = (req, res) => {
    let query: String = '\'diagnosis_text_de\': /.*' + req.body.qICD + '.*/i';
    console.log(query);
    this.model.find({
        'diagnosis_text_de': /.*depression.*/i
    }, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        res.json(docs);
    });
}
```

not working:

```
...
this.model.find({ query }, (err, docs)
...
```

Comment: Don't make it a "string". Make it an `Object` to begin with. `let query = { 'diagnosis_text_de': new RegExp('.*' + req.body.qICD + '.*','i') }; this.model.find(query,(err,docs) => {`. You cannot also use ES6 shorthand for `{ query }` because that implies "query" is the name of the key as well. That's why you use the Object form of construction instead.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Dear you can use mongodb operators $regex and $options as below

```
getByFullText = (req, res) => {
        let query = {
           diagnosis_text_de:{
            $regex: req.body.qICD,
            $options:"i"
          }
        }
        this.model.find(query,(err, docs) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            res.json(docs);
        });
    }
```